# Can't find 'Flight Mode' option in Windows 8 on Lenoveo G570

Tags: windows-8, wireless-networking, router, wifi-configuration

While surfing the Internet I just lost my wireless Internet. I am using a Lenovo G-570 laptop, a TP-LINK TL-WR841N router and the Windows 8 operating system.

I've searched Google and also visited [this link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/15287/windows-why-can-not-get-connected#1TC=windows-8) but haven't found a solution so far. I think the problem is with the Flight Mode setting of my laptop but unfortunately when I click on [image: this icon], it doesn't show WiFi on/off as before in the right side panel of Windows 8.

When I go to Wireless settings to disable Flight Mode, there is no such option as before. Here is a screenshot of my network options:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: my T400 has a physical switch on the front to the case.

Comment: Also i have and it is on, i can use Bluetooth only after enable it. It is on since four years in my laptop. I never off it and it is on now for sure.